# Ionic 4: failed facebook login with android when the native facebook app is installed

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in an app using Ionic 4. One of the requirements is the user can log in using Facebook. I follow this tutorial: https://www.djamware.com/post/5d949fa24ca99c5ee51238ef/ionic-4-tutorial-facebook-login-example, Facebook and works almost perfectly the functionality.

I am using this app:  https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Testing the app I found out the login fails when the native android Facebook app is installed in the device.

I have replicated, the experiment in three different devices.

**Here is the process when Facebook app is not installed in the device:**

[image]

Then when I do click in the Facebook login button, the Facebook login box appears perfectly:

[image]

Now, **when I tried to do the same when the facebook app is installed in the device** happens the following:

[image]

I do click in the facebook login button

[image]

The login box of the facebook app appears, and I logged in the the facebook app.

[image]

**But this error shows:**  "There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later"

I uninstalled the facebook app, and the login works again.

This is my login facebook function code:

```
    fbLogin() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      if (this.platform.is('android')) {

  this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 'connected') {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.getUserDetail(res.authResponse.userID);
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/tutorial");
      } else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
    }
});
}
```

I found this a similar app with another facebook login plugin for react:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/633

Their "workaround" was to force the app to call regular facebook login box like this:

```
if (Platform.OS === "android") {
            LoginManager.setLoginBehavior("web_only")
        }
```

Is any similar "workaround" or way to force to use the web facebook login box without call the facebook app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what I did was correct, I don't know if what I did was correct, but I wanted to put on record.

I check the plugin files. I studied one file in particular: **ConnectPlugin.java**

From what I see in others forums, I did the following

I added this library

```
import com.facebook.login.LoginBehavior;
```

And any line where the following command was:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(cordova.getActivity(), permissions);
```

In the line before I added this:

```
  // Create the request
            LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(cordova.getActivity(), permissions);
```

And worked perfectly. Now I can login in when the facebook added is installed.

I know this is a workaround.

Greettings.

Answer (score 0):

As **@Yorman** suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60644585/5094892), it could be a problem related to the Connect Plugin.
Check the Troubleshooting of the **cordova-plugin-facebook4** plugin:

- [Android](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#no-reply-from-login)
- [iOS](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#missing-facebookconnectplugin)